# Change image source by text detection

Tags: jquery, flickr

I'm currently developping a [graphic overlay application](http://flickeflu.com/explore) that shows [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com) content.

I want to replace images from users who have opted-out.

My html structure is as follow:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="imgbk">
      <img src='http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5312/7057785005_2966a34f1f.jpg'/>
      <a href='http://www.flickr.com/photos/85152114@N00/7057785005'>Link</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The string to be tested in this example is `85152114@N00` located in the href.

The href structure is always the same: **flickr.com / photos / userID / ImageID**

Until now, this was done server side, but huge traffic on my website forced me to do this client side. My jQuery knowledge is limited so I'm asking for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, Here is my new code based on your answers:

```
var OptOutArray = ["85152114@N00", "00000000@N00"];

$('img').each(function() {
  var matches = $(this).next().attr("href").split('/')[4];
  if ($.inArray(matches, OptOutArray) > -1) {
    $(this).attr("src", "http://core.flickeflu.com/doh.gif");
  }
});​
```

Example here : http://jsfiddle.net/jgYs8/

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you are looking for. However, if you want to grab that string, you could do the following:

```
var a = $('.imgbk a').attr('href');
var b = a.split('/');
alert(b[4]);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/AQw9X/

Basically, find the href attribute and then divide it at the `/`, placing each piece in an array named `b`.  I've alerted the result so you can see which item in the array to choose, but you can do whatever you want with it from there.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're looking for is a way to check all images in the page for any item that contain that specific code, you can do it like this;

```
var optOutstr = "85152114@N00";

$(img).each(function() {
   if (this.href.match(new RegExp("/" + optOutStr + "/")) {
       this.href = "whatever you want to replace the URL with";
       $(this).prev().attr("src", "whatever you want to replace the image with");
   }
});
```

If you had a whole list of codes to check against, there would be more efficient ways of checking it against a whole bunch of codes.

```
var optOutMap = {"85152114@N00": true, ....};

$(img).each(function() {
   var matches = this.href.match(/flickr.com\/photos\/([^\/]+)\//);
   if (matches && matches[1] in optOutMap) {
       this.href = "whatever you want to replace the URL with";
       $(this).prev().attr("src", "whatever you want to replace the image with");
   }
});
```